# Why aren't Google review texts shown in the language they were written in?

Tags: javascript, fetch, google-reviews, bengali

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJDzcum_mb_DkRk5QKN0b39C4&key=api_key`

I requested this API and received the review, but it appears that my review text is in Bengali while the displayed text is in English. How can I ensure that English reviews are shown in English and Bengali reviews are shown in Bengali or their respective languages?

I will display the language in which the user has provided a review on my web site.

Comment: You could use a package to determine all of that yourself. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@smodin/fast-text-language-detection

Comment: We can't tell you why some other server acts the way it does. This doesn't seem like a programming problem that you can solve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#optional-parameters) offers an optional parameter called `reviews_no_translations` that allows you to control this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJDzcum_mb_DkRk5QKN0b39C4&fields=reviews&reviews_no_translations=true&key=api_key`